# Родительный множественного от "буря"

Tags: грамматика

Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно будет: классификация бурей или классификация бурь?

Answer (score 3):

Если Вы имеете в виду пыльные, снежные и шквальные бури, то " классификация бурь".

Answer (score 2):

Грамматическая справка

1)В трех падежах множественного числа:  дательном, творительном и предложном – существительные  имеют одинаковые  окончания:  АМ/ЯМ, АМИ/ЯМИ, АХ/ЯХ

2) В И.п и Р.п. существительные могут иметь два вида окончаний в И.п. (окончания Ы/И и А/Я) и три вида окончаний в Р.п. (окончания ОВ/ЕВ, ЕЙ и нулевое).

3) Окончания бывают основные и вариантные. Основные окончания в Р.п.:

1-ое склонение: стен, земель – нулевое окончание

2-ое  склонение, мужской род: столов, жителей, листьев – окончание ОВ (твердый вариант) и окончания ЕЙ и ЕВ (мягкий вариант)
2-ое склонение, средний род:  окон, полей – нулевое окончание и окончание ЕЙ

3-ье  склонение: печЕй – окончание ЕЙ в Р.п.

Примечание

Обратим внимание на следующую закономерность: если в начальной форме слово имеет  ненулевое окончание (стена, окно), то в Р.п. окончание нулевое (стен, окон), и наоборот: при нулевом окончании в начальной форме (стол) наблюдается ненулевое окончание ОВ в Р.п.  (столов).

ОТВЕТ

**Буря - бури - нет бурь. Здесь нулевое (основное) окончание. Это обычное, законопослушное существительное (сущ. ж.р. имеют вариантные окончания как редкое исключение).**

Исключения:

а) Доля, сакля, свеча
Только вариантное окончание ЕЙ пишется в Р.п. существительных 1-ого  склонения: доля –  долЕй, сакля –  сАклей, свеча –  свечЕй

б) Особенности склонения существительного простынЯ проявляются только в Р.п. мн.числа, в котором используются ДВЕ ФОРМЫ: простЫнь (с основным нулевым окончанием для существительных 1-ого склонения) и более употребительная форма простынЕЙ с вариантным окончанием ЕЙ.